# WATERMARKING - iText example

Tags: itext

public static final String DATA = "resources/data/united_states.csv";

I need to know about what is the use of .csv file in WaterMarking.java example? And what is its content?

Answer (score 0):

It's an ordinary CSV file containing information about the states of the United States: http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/united_states.csv